# python код с библиотекой telebot игнорирует bot.polling

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

После запуска кода выводится 2 принта, и никаких ошибок, но второй принт не должен, ведь код должен был остановиться на `bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)`.

Токен правильный, библиотека telebot(3.0.0) установлена, изменять значения интервала тоже пробовал, напрямую передавать токен тоже, и запускать бота через консоль.

вот код:

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
print(bot.get_me())


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala (massage):
    bot.send_message(massage.chat.id, massage.text)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
print('out')
```

Answer (score 0):

bot.polling(none_stop=True) необходимо записывать в цикле while

```
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)    
    except Exception as e:
        time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло